# when postinstall script in package.json is executed while installing the vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created an extension and specified to run an installer file which will download the zip and extract the binary and place it some other folder.

But it is not working?

Please tell me what is the use of the post-install script in package.json while installing the extension.
And when this will be executed.

Thanks,
Akhil

Answer (score 1):

> `postinstall` Run AFTER the package is installed

Means that `postinstall` applies only for npm packages. (This is the downside of abuse *package.json* by other ecosystems).

If you want to run some logic (download, extract etc.), you can use the [`activation`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/extension-anatomy) event run the check (if a file exists for example) and if it failed, run the installation process.